# Need help pushing multiple rows into MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to push data from one file into another to build a MySQL query. The code below is where I am at. I am a bit lost and new to MySQL so any help would be great. The overall idea is to insert two records at the same time into the table.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
INSERT INTO heroes (plantTypes, asset, cost, energy, isSunProducer, isShooter, isExploding,
 sunFrequency, shootingFrequency, damage, userId) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,
?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

INSERT INTO enemies (zombieTypes, asset, damage, vx, energy, userId) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

> C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\RCB_Classwork\ProjectX\AyCarambaZombiesRising\node_modules\mysql\lib
>   \protocol\Parser.js:78
>           throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>
> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
>   at line 1

```
        projectX.createNewUserHeroes(['plantTypes', 'asset', 'cost', 'energy', 'isSunProducer', 'isShooter', 'isExploding', 'sunFrequency', 'shootingFrequency', 'damage', 'userId'], ['shooterOne', 'test', 100, 100, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 100, req.session.user_id], ['shooterTwo', 'test', 100, 100, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 100, req.session.user_id], function(data){

            console.log("This is the right heroes data: " + data)   
        });

        createNewUserHeroes: function(table, cols, vals, cb) {
              var queryString = 'INSERT INTO ' + table;
              queryString += ' (plantTypes, asset, cost, energy, isSunProducer, isShooter, isExploding, sunFrequency, shootingFrequency, damage, userId) ';
              queryString += 'VALUES';
              queryString += ' (';
              queryString = queryString + printQuestionMarks(vals.length);
              queryString += ')';
              queryString += ', ';
              queryString += '(';
              queryString = queryString + printQuestionMarks(vals.length);
              queryString += ') ';

              console.log(queryString)

              connection.query(queryString, vals, function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                cb(result);
              });
            },
```

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: INSERT INTO heroes (plantTypes, asset, cost, energy, isSunProducer, isShooter, isExploding,
 sunFrequency, shootingFrequency, damage, userId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,
?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
INSERT INTO enemies (zombieTypes, asset, damage, vx, energy, userId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) node_modules\mysql\lib
\protocol\Parser.js:78
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspo
nds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
at line 1

Comment: Gah, put that into the question then, too difficult to read in comments.

Comment: Added above. In the question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doubling the number of question marks in the prepared query, you need to double the array of values as well. You can do this by concatenating `vals` to itself:

```
connection.query(queryString, vals.concat(vals), function(err, result) {
    ...
});
```